# Umbraco 7. forms - path error when form transferred to document in Workflow (file upload)

Tags: forms, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a form with several fields that has a workflow to save as a document.
One of the fields is a File Upload.
This is matched to a document field of an Upload type.

All works well other than the File Upload in the resulting document has an error in the URL that is shown in the document:

It includes: ....umbraco/~/media/forms/upload.... 
Whereas it should be: ...media/forms/upload/...

The file uploaded is there, but the saved link is incorrect.

This does not seems to refer to the settings in FileSystemProviders.config or UmbracoForms.config
The later has a key for UploadStorageDirectory but has no effect.

Any suggestions would be great... John